# Quotient topology on $S^1$ is equal to the subspace topology

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to S^1$ defined $$f(t)=(\cos(2\pi t), \sin (2\pi t))$$
I have to prove that the quotient topology $\mathcal{U}_f$ induced by $f$ on $S^1$ is equal to the topology $\mathcal{U}$ on $S^1$ as a subespace of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

This is my idea let $V \in \mathcal{U}$ then $V= S^1 \cap U$ where $U$ is open on $\mathbb{R}^2$, and I have to prove that $f^{-1} (V) $ is open in $\mathbb{R}$.

The book gives the suggestion to prove that  $(S^1, \mathcal{U}_f)$ is homeomorphic to  $(S^1, \mathcal{U})$

Comment: Do you already know about compactness?

Comment: @DanielFischer  Not yet

Comment: Pity. That would have given a nice argument.

Comment: @DanielFischer Feel free to share the nice argument for the interested readers. :)

Comment: @Cornman By definition of final topologies and the continuity of the trigonometric functions in the standard topology we have $\mathcal{U} \subseteq \mathcal{U}_f$. Since $f(\mathbb{R}) = f([0,1])$, $S^1$ is compact in $\mathcal{U}_f$. Also $\mathcal{U}$ is Hausdorff.

Answer (score 1):

This follows from [the universal property of quotient maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_(topology)#Properties). All you need to show is that $f$ is a quotient map. And it is, because it is open as you can [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1245995/simplest-way-to-prove-that-eix-is-an-open-mapping-into-s1).